# Unable to communicate with DAC using SPI

Tags: stm32, spi, dac

I am trying to communicate with my [DAC](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5318.pdf) using SPI from my STM32L4 controller. I basically want to test if the SPI lines are working fine.i.e if I am able to transmit data and receive to and from the DAC respectively. I have configured the DAC pins as follows -

```
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RST_Pin|M_Z_Pin|TC_SB_Pin|LDAC_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PD_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /*Configure GPIO pins : READY_Pin LDAC_Pin BUSY_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = READY_Pin|BUSY_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RST_GPIO_Port,RST_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(M_Z_GPIO_Port,M_Z_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(TC_SB_GPIO_Port,TC_SB_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LDAC_GPIO_Port,LDAC_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(PD_GPIO_Port,PD_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_GPIO_Port,SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);



}
```

I want to read the contents of the status register, to which I have to send 0xC0 on the SPI line (as specified in the datasheet). In return, the DAC returns the contents of the status register. So, I have written the following code for it -

```
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi3;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USB_OTG_FS_USB_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI3_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);
uint8_t received_data[3],Data_to_send[3];
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_SPI3_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();

    while(1)
    {
         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_GPIO_Port,SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
     HAL_Delay(1);
     Data_for_try[0]=0xC0;
         HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi3,Data_to_send,received_data,3,100);
         HAL_Delay(1);
         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_GPIO_Port,SPI3_Chip_Select_DAC_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);

    }

}
```

But I am unable to get any data back as an acknowledgement from the DAC. I have checked that the SPI_CLOCK and the SPI_MOSI pin are getting the signals using an oscilloscope. Is there any way to check if the DAC is working fine?

Comment: 1. Schematics needed. Screenshot is enought.
2. Is there input voltage? Check all of VCC and GND.
3. Show `MX_SPI2_Init`. Be sure you configure `CPHA` and `CPOL` correctly.
4. Best solution to test SPI device is bit banding. Imitate waveform from datasheet. Read `General Configuration and Status Read Register` (page 36)

Comment: @Stephen Plyaskin - but before that, is the logic of my code correct? I am trying to write something into the status register and retrieve data from it.

Comment: It seems so. You are trying only read `GCSR` (0xC). After `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive` you should have result in buffer. What about SPI LSB MSB? Also show `MX_SPI3_Init` (not `MX_SPI2_Init`).

Comment: " I am unable to get any data back as an acknowledgement from the DAC". Could you elaborate ? As soon as a SPI master activates the SPI clock it will receive data from ther slave. So I assume you receive crap data ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean - No..as in, I was not receiving any data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support, but I was able to figure out the problem. I had to change the SPI settings as follows -

```
static void MX_SPI3_Init(void)
{
  /* SPI3 parameter configuration*/
  hspi3.Instance = SPI3;
  hspi3.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi3.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi3.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi3.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi3.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi3.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi3.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi3.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi3.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi3.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi3.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

The  `hspi3.Init.DataSize` was initialised to `SPI_DATASIZE_4BIT` instead of `SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT` which was the problem.